# Change the size of bookmark and cancel button from UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I'm trying to change the size of the bookmark button as well as the cancel button from the UISearchBar. I created a custom searchBar and searchBarController. I have been able to change the image for the bookmark button without any problems. Just as I have been able to change the height of the UITextField inside the searchbar. I'm however not sure how to get to the subviews of both buttons. If anyone happens to know how to do this that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

alright so I have the following method to be able to draw in the subview of the searchbar. The indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() is what I first used to change the size of my UITextField inside of the searchbar.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let index = indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() {
        // Access the search field
        let searchField: UITextField = (subviews[0]).subviews[index] as! UITextField


        // Set its frame.
        searchField.frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 10
        searchField.frame.origin.x = 5
        searchField.frame.origin.y = 5

        // Set the font and text color of the search field.
        searchField.font = preferredFont
        searchField.textColor = preferredTextColor

        // Set the background color of the search field.
        searchField.backgroundColor = barTintColor
    }
}
```

The code for indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews is as follows. It's a lil dirty since I'm trying to find the correct views to tap into.

```
func indexOfSearchFieldInSubviews() -> Int! {
        var index: Int!
        let searchBarView = subviews[0]

        for var i=0; i<searchBarView.subviews.count; ++i {
            if searchBarView.subviews[i].isKindOfClass(UITextField) {
                for subView in searchBarView.subviews[i].subviews{

                    //find the search icon and set the width/height for this.
                    if let bookmark = subView as? UIImageView{
                        bookmark.frame.size.height = 20
                        bookmark.frame.size.width = 20
                    }

                    //Find the Bookmark button and set the width/height for this.
                    if let button = subView as? UIButton{
                        button.frame.size.height = 40
                        button.frame.size.width = 40
                    }
                }
                index = i
                //break
            }
        }

        return index
    }
```

So as you can see I'm looking inside the subviews to get the search icon and set the size for this. I also try to catch the UIButton for the bookmark and when it finds this subview the size is being set as well. I need to see if this wil function on older OS versions as well tho. I'm still trying to find the subview for the cancel button no luck so far tho

Comment: As far as i know, you can change only the image, and the position, not the size

Comment: I figured out how to change the size of the bookmark image I'll post the code for this later. I haven't found a solution for the cancel button yet